# Android studio > set wallpaper resolution drop problem

Tags: java, android

I am developing a wallpaper application in android studio. The application photos are from API pexels.com. When I set the wallpaper in the emulator, there is no problem. However, when I try it on my own phone, it does not get full screen, it seems to zoom in and the resolution drops.My phone is Huawei p40 lite.There is no other phone to try, I don't know if the problem is in the codes. I'm very new to this subject.

```
public class setwallpaper extends AppCompatActivity {

    Intent intent;
    ImageView imageView;
    Button set;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_setwallpaper);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        final WallpaperManager wallpaperManager=WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        set=findViewById(R.id.set);
        imageView=findViewById(R.id.finalimage);
        intent=getIntent();

        String url=intent.getStringExtra("portrait");
        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(url).into(imageView);
        set.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap=((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                    wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"DONE",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {


    Context context;
    ArrayList<ImageModel> wallpaperlist;

    public Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<ImageModel> wallpaperlist) {
        this.context = context;
        this.wallpaperlist = wallpaperlist;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Adapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, null, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Adapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
                holder.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent browswerintent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        browswerintent.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.pexels.com/"));
                        browswerintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        context.startActivity(browswerintent);
                    }
                });

            }
        });

        Glide.with(context).load(wallpaperlist.get(position).getSrc().getPortrait()).into(holder.imageView);
        holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(context,setwallpaper.class);
                intent.putExtra("image",wallpaperlist.get(position).getSrc().getPortrait());
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return wallpaperlist.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textView;


        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imageView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            textView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview);
        }
    }
}
```

```
E/ResMng NATIVE_MSG_FILTER: endActivityTransaction: margin state not match
```